# how to find the second smallest of a vector?

Tags: c++

```
unsigned int i;
int min;
int num;

vector<int>sequence;

cout << "sequence: ";
for (i=0; cin.good(); ++i){
      cin >> num;
      sequence.push_back(num);
}

sequence.pop_back();

min = sequence.at(0);
for (i=0; i<sequence.size();++i){
    if (sequence.at(i)< min){
        min=sequence.at(i);
    }
}

cout << min << endl;
```

I want to find the second smallest of the users input in a vector. i have created a code to find the smallest. But i have no idea how to find the second smallest. I should do this without sorting the numbers. Can someone show me a way please?

Comment: [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and pick the 2nd element.

Comment: [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) might help.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yours is even better.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for your comment, but i have to find it without sorting the numbers.

Comment: Else manually, you can take the smallest from your collection ignoring the minimum item (and not value in case of tie). or have a *stack* of the 2 smaller items, instead of only one.

Comment: Maybe [std::partial_sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort)? Why not sorting the numbers? If this is homework and you have to implement a sorting function yourself, you should probably rephrase your question.

Comment: `nth_element` is probably not considered sorting.

Comment: In a sequence like `1 2 1`, do you consider that the second smallest element is `1` or `2`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do in `O(n)` run time complexity. sorting will take `O(n log n)` time complexity to run. You just need two variables in this case to find the second minimum.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int i;
    int min;
    int num;

    vector<int>sequence;

    cout << "sequence: ";
    for (i=0; cin.good(); ++i){
        cin >> num;
        sequence.push_back(num);
    }
    sequence.pop_back();

    int minimum = INT_MAX, secondmin = INT_MAX;

    for (i=0; i<sequence.size();++i){

       if (minimum > sequence[i]) {

           secondmin = minimum;
           minimum = sequence[i];

       }else if ( secondmin > sequence[i] ) {

           secondmin = sequence[i];

       }
    }
    cout << "answer is "<< secondmin << endl;


}
```

OUTPUT

```
sequence: 1
2
3
4
end
answer is 2
```

Comment: @Jarod42 agreed

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    decltype( v )::value_type min1 = 0, min2 = 0;

    if ( not ( v.size() < 2 ) )
    {
        auto minmax = std::minmax( v[0], v[1] );
        min1 = minmax.first;
        min2 = minmax.second;

        for ( decltype( v )::size_type i = 2; i < v.size(); i++ )
        {
            if ( v[i] < min1 )
            {
                min2 = min1;
                min1 = v[i];
            }
            else if ( v[i] < min2 )
            {
                min2 = v[i];
            }
        }
    }


    std::cout << "min1 = " << min1 << ", min2 = " << min2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
min1 = 0, min2 = 1
```

Or you can write your own algorithm as for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

template <typename ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator second_min( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last )
{
    ForwardIterator first_minimum  = first;
    ForwardIterator second_minimum = last;

    if ( first != last )
    {
        while ( ++first != last )
        {
            if ( *first < *first_minimum )
            {
                second_minimum = first_minimum;
                first_minimum  = first;
            }
            else if ( second_minimum == last || *first < *second_minimum )
            {
                second_minimum = first;
            }
        }
    }

    return second_minimum;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    auto minimum = second_min( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) );

    if ( minimum != std::end( v ) )
    {
        std::cout << "second minimum = " << *minimum << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
second minimum = 1
```

Comment: the loop should start from index 2, you are ignoring the third element with index 2

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int i;
    int min;
    int num;

    vector<int>sequence;

    cout << "sequence: ";
    for (i = 0; cin.good(); ++i) {
        cin >> num;
        sequence.push_back(num);
    }
    sequence.pop_back();
    sort(sequence.begin(), sequence.end());

    cout << " Second smallest : "<<sequence[1] << endl;
}
```

Comment: question states "I should do this without sorting the numbers" hence this does not answer the question